# Wallpaper not rendered on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, gnome, compiz, themes, desktop-background

I'm experiencing an issue where there is a black background on Ubuntu startup and whenever I open or close anything it leaves shadows on that black background.

I'm using compiz and a custom theme from here http://www.noobslab.com/2013/05/mac-os-x-theme-for-ubuntu-1304-raring.html

Though reverting the theme to Ubuntu's default theme doesn't solve this issue.

Also, surprisingly when I shutdown or lock my computer, it mysteriously shows the correct background image.

Answer (score 0):

First, install `gnome-tweak-tool` with `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool -y` in the terminal. Now run `gnome-tweak-tool` and check Desktop > Have file manager handle the desktop > On/Off. This needs to be on in order for nautilus to manage the desktop background along with icons.

If you are having compiz issues, `sudo rm ~/.compiz ~/.config/compiz-1 -R` then logging out and logging back in should fix it.

Comment: Didn't work. :(